# Lookup field on VF page do not populate values

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, lookup

I have this registration form (VF Page) that creates a contact up on submission. Contact have a lookup field mypartner__c which looks up mypartner__c custom object. User should be able to select partner as part of their application submission.

It works perfectly fine when logged in as Salesforce user and access the page as 
mysalesforce.com/apex/lkpPage. However the popup do not populate values when same page is accessed through a force.com site

Here is simplified version of page code:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardController="contact">
<apex:pageBlock title="Registration">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageblocksection title="Test" collapsible="false">
<apex:inputfield value="{!contact.FirstName}"/>
<apex:inputfield value="{!contact.LastName}"/>
<apex:inputfield value="{!contact.MyPartner__c}" /> <!--This is the lookupfield -->
</apex:pageblocksection>
</apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Site guest user profile have all required permission to both contact partner objects. I even tried ViewAll on partner object just to check if permission is a problem. But look up wont show any values. Popup appears when lens icon is clicked but do not show any values.

I still think this is a permission error. Can someone please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the lookup page for your site
site details> standard pages related list> Edit >enable the lookup page & search page and save.

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What are the sharing settings or org wide defaults on the partner object. Please check these and ensure you have the appropriate sharing settings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. OWD for MyPartner__c object is Public Read Write and for contact it is Controlled by Parent.

Comment: Is contact the master for Partner. In that case you may need to check the sharing settings on contact as well.

Comment: Yes, Contact is master. Site Guest Profile have Read and Create permission on Contact object and have visibility to all contact fields.

Comment: As partner visibility is controlled by Contact. The guest user should have visibility on all the contacts. Then you should be able to see values in the partner lookup field